# Using custom type attribute in <script> tags such as jQuery's text/x-jquery-tmpl

Tags: jquery-templates, custom-attribute

I noticed that [jquery's beta template plugin](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) is using, the type attribute "text/x-jquery-tmpl"

e.g

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
```

I've not seen custom use of the type attribute in the past. Has anyone seen current examples of this in use or perhaps ways mere mortal developers such as I can use this in our own code?

I presume that it's sort of a MIME type, however I would of thought that MIME type support was up to the browser. So I would of assumed that custom MIME types would be unsupported?

Comment: Please note the jquery template plugin is no longer under development if anyone comes across this question now.

Comment: The linkedin api also has some good examples of using the type attribute https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/javascript-api-tutorial

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The type actually does indicate what sort of script is there.  If the browser doesn't understand it, it should ignore it.  In this case, it's a convenient and semantic sort of way to include the source of the template without displaying it on the screen.

Usually with jquery template, you'll give it an id and refer to it that way with your $(id).tmpl call.

script def here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#idx-scripting_language

examples of tmpl here:
http://api.jquery.com/tmpl/

Comment: Thanks @Wesley Tarle, so even though the browser does not know how to "render / interact" with it, other scripts can? e.g. jQuery can interact with the template, even though the browser doesn't know what it is?

Comment: yes I think the jQuery templating engine just grabs the contents out of the script tag storage with .innerHTML and goes to town.

Comment: Thanks @Wesley Tarle, do you know of any other examples other than jQuery template? As it's funny as I've only ever seen jQuery template use this feature.

Comment: Nope, I've only seen that tag used to legitimately switch from Javascript to VBScript in IE.  I think it's a cool way to store arbitrary text on the page!

Comment: I agree it's very cool @Wesley Tarle. It's interesting how jQuery can still get to the data inside <script> even though it's not marked as javascript. I'm guessing that even though the browsers "view engine" cannot display it, it's DOM still alows access to it.

Comment: There's an interesting write up from John Resig about micro-templates (I'm guessing the predessesor to the tmpl plug), http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/ - the comments are pretty interesting as well.

Comment: Yes, @Alex. The browser _generally_ will build up the DOM exactly as you specify it, unrecognized tag names, attributes, and all. Whether those attributes, tag names, and content have any meaning or behavior in an HTML document is a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

No, MIME are provided by the server to identify resources. The browser then acts on the types it recognizes.

Yes, in the HTTP connection the browser lists the types it can recognize so the server can choose types that fit better (an example here would be HTML 5 and video, where you have some codec options and the browser may support only a subset).

In this case, the specific MIME helps to signal the browser a warning: "This is not normal Javascript, don't act on it like if it was."

Comment: Thanks @Pere, so how does the browser know how to interpret it in the jquery template example, as I'm guessing that browsers haven't yet implemented x-jquery-tmpl? Perhaps javascript can still interact with it?

Comment: I'm not sure that the browser does anything in there, probably is Javascript acting, but I don't know the exact mechanism, sorry about that.

Comment: No worries thanks @Pere, have you seen any examples / write up's about other "types" for the script tags?