# HTML make your own <script type="text/language">?

Tags: javascript, html, text

Javascript is put in `text/javascript` and Coffeescript also has support for it, but I was wondering it there was a way to make my own? I'd like to make a Golfscript interpreter that anyone can do `<script type="text/golfscript">` for and it would be put through the interpreter.

Comment: What have you already researched?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using custom type attribute in <script> tags such as jQuery's text/x-jquery-tmpl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452142/using-custom-type-attribute-in-script-tags-such-as-jquerys-text-x-jquery-tmpl)

Comment: When it comes to running the code "CoffeeScript is a little language that **compiles into JavaScript**".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Leaving aside the (usually) unrealistic options of persuading all your users to install a browser extension or custom browser…

The only way you can do this is with a programming language already supported by the browser. In most cases that means JavaScript.

You can access the content of the element through the DOM:

```
document.querySelector('script[type="text/golfscript"]').textContent
```

… and then have a parser and interpreter written in JS.

You will probably want to use `querySelectorAll` and a loop.

---

NB: `text/golfscript` doesn't appear to be a registered MIME type. You'll probably want to use the `x` prefix to mark it as experimental and use `application` since it is a programming language: `application/x-golfscript`.

Comment: TIL what the `x-` is for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/working-with-paper-js/

These people seem to be doing what you are asking about.  I don't know how, but maybe this will get you started.

```
<!-- Load the Paper.js library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/paper.js"></script>
<!-- Load external PaperScript and associate it with myCanvas -->
<script type="text/paperscript" src="js/myScript.js" canvas="myCanvas">
</script>
```